# Breakpoint during Debug process of a project of Type "DLL" including exernal "exe"

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a plugin for a program ("M") using Vc++. This Cpp.project is of type "dll".

```
Project properties->Configuration Type-> dll
Project properties->Debugging->command-> external program("M.exe")
```

The normal workflow is:

1: build project,

2: Write an XML-file.

3: Using the XML file and the DLL files of the project, I can make the plugin.

4: Install that plugin in the program and then I can use it.

[More Info about the process](http://www.developer.faro.com/md_pages_guides_plugin_app.html)

Now if I put some breakpoints in the code to explore it,  how can I debug it?

Currently, I am doing

Rebuild the project,     make the App again,     install it.
It is tedious and reports:

```
Information not available, no symbols loaded for .dll ([![see for more info][2]][2]
```

How can I do it in a better way? Any idea?

Comment: Did you look at the output tab of Visual Studio? Did it complain about not loading symbols for your dll? Did the breakpoints turn from red to white?

Comment: ***Information not available, no symbols loaded for .dll*** Did you copy the `.pdb` file to the same location as the `.dll`

Comment: Use Debug > Windows > Modules.  Locate the DLL in the list > right-click > Symbol Load Information.  Tells you where it looked for the PDB file, ensure it is present.